# ASP.NET Web API: Change Request Headers

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

A JavaScript client that I have no control over is sending the incorrect HTTP request headers to my Web API services. More specifically, it's using a library that is sending an incorrect OData header.

Is there any way that I can intercept the HTTP request before it hits my services? Can I add/remove/update headers or query string info?

For instance, if I receive the following HTTP header:

```
GET /Some/API HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com:80
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
```

I'd like to know how to modify it to the following before the OData libraries take over:

```
GET /Some/API HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com:80
MaxDataServiceVersion: 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The header isn't incorrect.  Your client expects an OData v2 service and even if you did manipulate the headers, it probably won't be able to understand the response from your server.

But you could use a simple HTTP proxy to rewrite the headers if you really want to try that route.

If you do that, make sure your OData server supports the Atom format because the OData JSON format changed completely between versions 2 and 4, so there's no way that JavaScript client will understand it.  The Atom format changed as well, but if the client's parser is extremely lenient, it might work.

Comment: Understood on the OData version concern, but we think there's simply a bug in the library we're using that's specific to the MaxDataServiceVersion header that we're hoping to get around by changing request headers. I was hoping you'd say that using an ASP.NET filter could modify incoming request headers, but we can always explore the proxy route.